# How do you set a dynamically created panel to false in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, panel

I have on my screen design Panel1(left half), and panel2 through 10(right half), the panels on the right half are named based on data from a database.

I need to be able to click on a button in panel1 and when I do so, I need to set visibility to false for the current panel on the right half and set visibility to true that is referenced from the button click.  I know that I can do the following but I think this is just way too much overhead and there has to be a better solution than this:

```
For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
     If control.visible = true Then
          control.visible = false        
          exit  
Next
```

Panel that the visibility that needs to be set to false was dynamically created so it can not just be accessed by just name, otherwise that would solve my issue easily.

I seen this bit of code elsewhere and it would make my life easier, however not sure how to implement it dynamically when the panels are created, since the name of the panels are unknown at creation.

This bit of code to be able to reference the panels directly.

```
Dim machinePanel As Panel = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Item("pnl" & strMTB & strMachineID), Panel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but "is referenced from the button click", so I'll assume that the text of the button refers to the panel name.

Create a method that handles the visibility

```
Private Sub SetPanelVisibility(button As Button)
    'panel that the button is in
    Dim leftPanel = CType(button.Parent, Panel)

    'get right panels and ignore left
    Dim rightpanels = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel).Where(Function(x) x.Name <> leftPanel.Name)

    'set visibility of each panel.
    For Each panel In rightpanels
        panel.Visible = panel.Name = button.Text
    Next
End Sub
```

To call the method just pass the button in on the click event. e.g.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetPanelVisibility(sender)
End Sub
```

Comment: So the button name is btnRandomData and the panel that it references would be pnlRandomData.  RandomData is the same for both.

Comment: To tie them together it may be best to use the Tag property (which both panel and buttons have). You won't then have to look for a panel, just look for a control that has that tag.

Comment: So I don't know if I am searching google wrong or not but can't find anything on accessing a panel by tag.  I do understand the idea though, however accessing a panel by tag is great for making it visible.  What would be the best way of finding the panel that is visible to make it not visible?

Comment: The above code does both i.e. makes the visible panel invisible and sets the new panel visible. It does a simple loop through all the panels and makes the changes based on the panel name matching the button text. There won't be much impact on speed doing it that way.

Comment: Okay so I only seeing it set the visibility to true, but I don't see where it is setting visibility to false anywhere?

Comment: It's panel.Name = button.Text, which acts as a Boolean

Comment: okay not use to seeing notation like that, but I get it.  We are going to set the visibility to the value of the expression  panel name compared to button text.  So I have to make a small adjustment to that because my buttons are named the same as the panel with the exception buttons start with btn and panels start with pnl.  But I totally understand it now.  This is the first time I am writing a full fledge piece of software where 75% of it is created dynamically.  So when you can't see the exact code some things aren't as obvious.